# Strip whitespace from a string in-place?

Tags: c

I saw this in a "list of interview questions". Got me wondering.

Not limited to whitespace necessarily, of course, easily generalized to "removing some specific character from a string, in-place".

My solution is:

```
void stripChar(char *str, char c = ' ') {
  int x = 0;
  for (int i=0;i<strlen(str);i++) {
    str[i-x]=str[i];
    if (str[i]==c) x++;
  }
  str[strlen(str)-x] = '\0';
}
```

I doubt there is one more efficient, but is there a solution that is more elegant?

**edit**: totally forgot I left `strlen` in there, it is most definitely not efficient

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all, `i<strlen(str)` is always an inefficient idiom for looping over a string. The correct loop condition is simply `str[i]`, i.e. loop until `str[i]` is the null terminator.

With that said, here's the simplest/most concise algorithm I know:

```
for (size_t i=0, j=0; s[j]=s[i]; j+=!isspace(s[i++]));
```

**Note:** My solution is for the question as written in the subject (whitespace) as opposed to the body (particular character). You can easily adapt it if needed.

Comment: Wow `j+=!isspace(s[i++])` is really clever.

Comment: Even more concise is `while(s[!(s[i]==32)?j++:j]=s[i++]);` but you have to set up the variables outside it so. However, I would advise the OP to _never_ use either of these in any real code of course.

Comment: @SethCarnegie: or even `(s[i]-32)`

Comment: The reason I wrote it with a for loop is to keep it clean and readable. The loop condition and increment operation are kept in their proper places; the only thing that's slightly non-canonical is doing the assignment in the loop condition, and the reason I put it there rather than the (empty) loop body is that the assignment needs to happen even on the last (terminating) iteration.

Answer (score 17):

C doesn't have default arguments, and if you're programming in C++ you should use `std::string` and `remove_if` from `<algorithm>`.

You definitely *can* make this more efficient, by eliminating the calls to `strlen`, which are turning an O(N) algorithm into an O(N<sup>2</sup>) algorithm, and are totally unnecessary -- you're scanning the string anyway, so just look for the NUL yourself.

You can also make this more C-idiomatic, by using two pointers instead of array indexing.  I'd do it like this:

```
void strip_char(char *str, char strip)
{
    char *p, *q;
    for (q = p = str; *p; p++)
        if (*p != strip)
            *q++ = *p;
    *q = '\0';
}
```

Comment: Wow this is so simple and elegant.

Answer (score -1):

```
void prepend(char* s,char ch){
    int len = strlen(s);
    memmove(s, s + 1, len - 1);
    s[len - 1] = '\x0';
}


void RemoveWhitespace(char* InStr, char ch){
     int n(0);

if (InStr == NULL){
    return;
}
else if ((*InStr) == '\x0'){
    return;
}   
else if ((*InStr) != ch){
    RemoveWhitespace(InStr + 1,ch);
}
else{
    while ((*InStr) == ch){
        prepend(InStr,InStr[0]);
        n++;
    }
    RemoveWhitespace(InStr + n,ch);
}
}
```

Comment: @Steven Lu, Recursion may lead stack overflow but since all the other answers were iterative, I decided to post this recursive implementation. In addition, I know memmove and strlen are expensive operations.